# PlacePicker Without Opening Widget Screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I have implemented Google Maps in my App and doing reverse geocoding when clicking on map.Im using [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) API. but it gives me more than one result on Single tap. I know why Google behave like this.

Then I look into `PlacePicker widget for Android`, but Im unable to use that widget without opening another Map screen to pick place.

What I want is that I want to use my Google Map screen to get tapped place instead of opening PlacePicker screen. I just want `PlacePicker` work with my implemented  Map i.e want `PlacePicker` to respond map click and give place without opening widget if this is not possible then inform me about other solution to get exactly one and correct place on Map tap? Thank you in advance

**Updated**

Why Im getting closed vote for question? it is not too broad? Simply,I want to know whether is it possible to use Google Map (MapView|SuportFragment) as PlacePicker's  main screen. Have look code below

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
// I don't want this line, Don't want PlacePicker to open another Map Screen to allow user to pick place. 
startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

now look at below code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
        String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

above code is executed when user pick a place from `PlacePicker` screen and that screen returns a `Intent` with picked place. Is there any way to make that type of 'Intent' on Google Map tap with lat,lng? so that I could get Place detail. I don't want to user reverse geocoding as it gives me many results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my problem, To get rid of reverse geocoding to many results and to get clicked place I use following code

```
 googleMap.setOnPoiClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPoiClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPoiClick(PointOfInterest pointOfInterest) {
        String SS="";
       isPOI=true;
       poiPlaceID=pointOfInterest.placeId;
        // Then using Google PlaceDetail API with placeId, It gives me exact Location click
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Donot know anything about the google geo api or PlacePicker api.

The google independent android standard way would be to use "ACTION_PICK" with a [geo uri](https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/data#geo).

For more infos see https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/Android-Geo-howto.

This only works if you have installed a [geo-pick-aware app](https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/Android-Geo-aware-apps) that supports geo-pick.

Note: you do not have to use the lib. All you need to do is to decode the geo-uri returned by activity result

Comment: I have found solution based on POI Events